# Details about segment selectors in x86 system

Tags: x86, paging, cpu-registers, segment

I'm studying about protection ring of x86 system.

[Examples of accessing data segments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYKea.png)

In this picture, there are segment selectors.
My questions are...

1. segment selectors are in the RAM?
2. who create segment selectors? automatically?
3. one segment can have multiple segment selectors?
4. relationship btw segment selectors and segment registers?
5. this kind of structure(i.e, paged segmentation, segment selectors, ...) are used on modern system?

Thanks.

Comment: To shortcut things, the answer to #5 is No.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then, modern system use just paging to manage memory?

Comment: @NateEldredge I feel like that's a big oversimplification. They are used, but they are used in such a way that their effect doesn't matter. Without the segmentation structures you cannot achieve privilege separation on x86. Paging only enforces the privilege levels, but something (the GDT) has to define them. Paging itself is useless if user code can execute `mov cr3`, for example.

Comment: @DarkAtom: Without setting up a GDT, you can't even switch to protected mode or long mode at all, since you can't jump to a 32-bit or 64-bit code segment.  So yeah I guess it's fair to say you'd have no privilege separation / memory protection, but that's because you'd be stuck in real mode without the possibility of enabling paging at all!  (Or could just changing the control-register bits put you in 16-bit protected mode, with segment bases unchanged from real mode?  You couldn't handle interrupts without a GDT since that involves loading a new CS:[er]IP specified in the IDT.)

Comment: @PeterCordes While I'm sure it's undefined behavior according to the manual, you can probably switch to protected mode and even long mode. I think you can set `CR0.PE` 
 (maybe even `CR0.PG`, `CR4.PAE` and `EFER.LME`) and use the real mode descriptor caches. You probably can't get out of 16-bit mode though. EDIT: Didn't see your edit so I wrote this :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will attempt to explain this in terms as simple as possible.

#### What is segmentation?

Segmentation is the idea of dividing memory into segments. These segments have a **base address** and a **limit** (or size).

Traditionally, in Real Mode (DOS era), segments were defined as follows:

```
base_address = segment_register * 16
limit = 64 KiB
```

In Protected Mode, however, segments are no longer defined like this. Instead, there's a table which contains details about every segment. As a bonus, it not only describes the base address and the limit, but also the privilege required to use it (that's why it's called **Protected** Mode) and if it's a 16-bit or 32-bit segment.

---

#### The Global Descriptor Table ([GDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table))

The GDT is a table (i.e. array) set up by an operating system in memory which contains **descriptors**. These come in 2 types: segment descriptors (which define segments, along with all their attributes) and system descriptors (which define various OS structures in memory, some are important, some not so much).

The operating system tells the CPU where this table is located using the privileged [`lgdt`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/lgdt:lidt) instruction. However, if you attempt it in user-mode code, it will fault.

#### Segment descriptors

Segment descriptors define **segments**. See below to see how to actually load and use one. A segment descriptor has [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Descriptor_Table#/media/File:SegmentDescriptor.svg) format.

#### Segment selectors

Segment selectors are simply **indexes** into the GDT. They have a specific format in which the last 3 bits are used for other purposes (bit 2 is the Table Indicator, while bits 1-0 are the Requested Privilege Level). Only bits 15-3 describe the actual index. For example, selector `0x20` indicates index 4 (starting from 0) in the GDT.

#### Segment registers

The segment registers (`CS`, `DS`, `ES`, `FS`, `GS` and `SS`) are designed to store these selectors while they are in use. However, when they are not in use, they can be stored in memory or in any other place.

The **NULL** selector acts as a sort of NULL pointer from C. You can freely load it into segment registers, but any attempt to use it will fault.

Example: a memory access such as `[ebx]` will be relative to the segment base described by `DS` (or you can explicitly specify a segment register, such as `[es:ebx]`).

In Real Mode, such an instruction would have accessed the memory address `ds * 16 + ebx`. However, in Protected Mode, the base address is taken from the GDT (at the index indicated by `DS`), and the offset `ebx` is added to it. The good part is that if the descriptor indicated by `DS` is privileged, but the code making the memory access is not, it will fault with a General Protection Fault.

---

#### How are segment descriptors created?

The segment descriptors, as mentioned before, are part of the GDT and are created by the operating system. The segment selectors are (usually) given by the OS to the application. The application is free to set its own selectors if it wants, provided that the corresponding descriptors exist and are accessible (which in modern OSes is almost never the case).

#### Can you have multiple segment selectors?

One can and always has multiple selectors. This is because `CS` must reference a code segment descriptor, while everything else references a data segment descriptor.

#### Isn't it slow to access the GDT for every memory access?

It is. If that was the case, the CPU would have to access the correct GDT entry every time someone accessed memory, in order to validate privilege levels and to get the segment base and limit for calculations.

Fortunately, the CPU caches these entries (into the so-called descriptor caches) whenever you load a segment register. This is why loading a segment register is a rather expensive operation. These caches are then guaranteed to remain unchanged until you reload the corresponding segment register again. This includes switching out of Protected Mode, without restoring the descriptor caches (and this is how you enter the [Unreal Mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_mode)).

---

#### Segmentation on modern 32-bit systems

Segmentation cannot be disabled on x86, but it can be...well...bypassed. By setting all descriptors as having base 0 and a 4GiB limit, you essentially bypass all advantages and disadvantages of segmentation.

All modern systems use **paging** to achieve memory protection. However, segmentation is still required because it enforces the privilege level. Each descriptor in the GDT has a DPL (Descriptor Privilege Level) field. This is what enforces the so-called privilege Rings. If a user-mode application had access to Ring 0 selectors, it could execute privileged instructions and bypass every protection mechanism, including paging.

Apart from that, there are a couple of system structures (defined in the GDT using system descriptors) such as the Task State Segment (TSS) which are critical for the OS. The TSS, for example, ensures that when any transition from Ring 3 to Ring 0 happens, the stack (`SS:ESP`) is switched to a well-known kernel stack, since the user-mode stack can't be trusted.

Segmentation is still used for the `FS` and `GS` registers. In Windows, `FS` references a descriptor which points to the [Thread Information Block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_Thread_Information_Block), while `GS` is NULL.

#### Segmentation on 64-bit systems

In 64-bit mode, segmentation is **almost** disabled. The only selector that truly matters is `CS`, which sets the privilege level according to the DPL field. The `DS`, `ES` and `SS` registers are unused. `DS` and `ES` are set to 0 (in 64-bit mode the NULL selector does nothing, it doesn't fault when used), while `SS` still points to a descriptor (loading NULL faults), though I'm not really sure why it can't be 0.

However, the descriptors can't set a base or a limit*. Essentially, the CPU creates the same environment that has to be created manually in 32-bit mode. Memory protection is achieved by paging, which is mandatory in 64-bit mode.

There is a way to set the base for the `FS` and `GS` selectors (see the [`WRFSBASE`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrfsbase:wrgsbase) and [`WRGSBASE`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/wrfsbase:wrgsbase) instructions). This doesn't affect the GDT entries at all (they still only have space for a 32-bit base), but instead directly modifies the descriptor caches (the registers themselves are typically set to 0). Windows 64-bit uses `GS` instead of `FS` to point to the TIB.

---

* Some CPUs support setting a segment limit in the last 4GiB of the 256TiB address space. From what I understand, this was done to facilitate software virtualization before hardware virtualization (VT-x and AMD-V) was a thing.

Comment: The segment "descriptor caches" aren't normal caches like L1d or the TLB; it's architecturally defined when they read the GDT, and guaranteed that they won't be evicted randomly, so they can be out of sync with the contents of the GDT.  Or even switch back to real mode and segment bases/limits will keep their internal state.

Comment: In [How can a 32-bit x86 CPU start with reset vector 0xFFFFFFF0 even though it starts in 16-bit real mode?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/27038) I explained a way of thinking about them that IMO makes more sense: internal state that you can write by writing segment registers in real or protected mode (with different semantics depending on mode).

Comment: @PeterCordes Never meant to imply that descriptor caches are like normal caches. I will edit it now.

Comment: I only skimmed your answer; I don't think you really imply anything either way, but *Isn't it slow to access the GDT for every memory access?* does hint that way.  I just remember finding the word "cache" in "descriptor cache" was the opposite of helpful for me in understanding how things worked, because it implies lots of things that aren't true about segment base/limit and other internal state.  It's basically extra internal registers, not a cache at all.  (But that was a design decision Intel made; it *could* have been just a cache that could re-access the GDT at any point.)

Comment: *though I'm not really sure why [SS] can't be 0.* - SS sets the stack-address size, IIRC, like whether `push`/`pop` implicitly use `sp` or `esp` in 32-bit protected mode.  In long mode, the only valid setting is 64-bit, but maybe it was easier for hardware to require something?  Or for SS:RSP to need to exist for TSS reasons?  I've never looked at the full details of exactly how interrupt / TSS stuff works.  But yeah it seems like allowing SS=0 (including in the TSS) would have been a valid design, it's just not what AMD chose.  Perhaps requiring it made fewer special-cases in their HW.

Comment: @PeterCordes The reason I find it weird is because Ring 0 is allowed to load a null `SS` selector and use it. In fact, in every interrupt where a privilege transfer happens, `SS` is zeroed automatically by the CPU (after being saved on the stack). The kernel basically always has a zeroed SS, since it has no reason to bother changing it. The only restriction is that the RPL must match the CPL. Loading a null selector only faults at Ring 3.

Comment: In 64-bit mode only, I hope it is clear. In 32 and 16-bit modes, SS faults when loaded with 0 at any CPL.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks.  (And `mov eax, 3` / `mov ss, eax` also faults in user-space, so there's no such thing as a RPL=3 null descriptor, or at least it doesn't work for SS.)  It might just be the case that AMD didn't think it was that valuable to allow SS=0, so didn't spend the extra transistors (or microcode instructions?) to make the RPL==CPL check conditional on not being in 64-bit mode for SS. They were quite conservative with AMD64, leaving a lot of warts unfixed, e.g. to minimize the amount of extra transistors in decoders, so they wouldn't be stuck with dead weight if it didn't catch on.